# How do I remove the cover and caps on my old electric baseboard heaters?

Tags: heater, baseboard

I cannot find any directions or videos as to how to open up my baseboard heaters. A couple of my heaters are sagging off the wall as the screws holding them to the drywall have pulled away from the wall.
I want to reinstall screws with anchors to avoid this problem in the future.

The issue is they were new apartment installs in 1999 and I can’t find disassembly information. Online videos contain more modern residential models.

[image: no]

Comment: what happens if you remove all screws

Comment: Doesn’t loosen anything up and I wasn’t sure what it would impact.

Comment: They usually lift straight up, or swing up and out like a gas grill lid.

Comment: Took screws off and was able to remove end cap! Thanks. I will work on Center cap and other end cap!

Comment: Drywall is made literally of chalk and paper. Get a broken off scrap of it at the home store and tear it apart and see for yourself.  It's not even very good chalk. Expecting it to *actually hold things* is optimistic.  I would look for studs to screw into.

Answer (score 1):

They often simply flex into place and clip top and bottom with tabs. The end caps may slide off to the side. Yours may be stuck with paint.

Comment: I will take a closer look.  There were four small hex head, self tapping screws just underneath the face on a small lip but didn’t loosen anything. I thought maybe they were holding up the inner heat fins??

Comment: @KevinBlacklock  Those screws sound more like they are to hold the facing/housing together than to hold anything else.

Comment: Looking at the screws it looks like they are at bottom corners of the two end caps and also at bottom corners of of the sleeve type cap which is in the middle or corner.

Comment: It would make sense that they would unclog giving some access to innards but are definitely painted over. May try an easy pry with flat head screw driver or wait for more feedback.

Comment: Was able to remove screws and pop off one end cap. Should be able to get middle cap and other end off to get at wall screw.